# Vue / Vuex - correct way to create and set store items from main object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am somewhat new to Vue and trying figure out the correct way to take a "master" store object and then run some functions to strip keys and rename other keys and create an altered version of it and save that to the store as a new store item.

I dispatch a "loadData" action in `created()` of App.js and then calling a local function 'prepareData' to take the `mapState["eventsData"]` and manipulate it to create two new store items.

What's happening is the 'master' `eventsData` object is getting changed by my functions.
Also, on the initial page load, this.eventsData (the main object) consoles as the dreaded `[__ob__: Observer]`. The next page load it has the data because it's getting it from localStorage at that point.

**App.js** (prepareData() is just a key/value tweaking function).

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      calendarData: [],
      gridData: [],
    };
  },
  computed: mapState(["eventsData"]),
  created: function () {
    state.commit("initializeStore");
    this.$store.dispatch("loadData"); // this loads then commits "setEventsData"
    this.prepareData();
  },
  methods: {
    prepareData() {
      this.calendarData = this.eventsData.forEach((event, i) => {
        delete event.artist_supporting;
        delete event.genre;
        delete event.venue;
        delete event.venue_city;
        delete event.venue_state;
        delete event.capacity;
        delete event.announce_date;
        delete event.onsale_date;
        delete event.promoter;
        delete event.business_unit;
        delete event.show_type;
        delete event.confirm_date;
        delete event.cancelled_date;
        delete event.status;

        event.venue_id = `event_${i}`;
        event.id = event.venue_id;
        event.title = event.artist_headliner;
        event.startDate = event.event_date;

        delete event.venue_id;
        delete event.artist_headliner;
        delete event.event_date;

        let date = new Date(event.startDate);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        event.startDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
      });
      this.gridData = this.eventsData.forEach((event) => {
        let date = new Date(event.event_date);
        console.log(event.event_date);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        event.event_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
      });
      state.commit("setCalendarData", this.calendarData);
      state.commit("setGridData", this.gridData);
    },
  },
};
```

**index/store.js**

```
 mutations: {
    initializeStore(state) {
      state.eventsData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("eventsData")) || [];
      state.calendarData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("calendarData")) || [];
      state.gridData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gridData")) || [];
    },
    setEventsData: (state, data) => {
      state.eventsData = data;
      localStorage.setItem("eventsData", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    setCalendarData: (state, data) => {
      state.calendarData = data;
      localStorage.setItem("calendarData", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    setGridData: (state, data) => {
      state.gridData = data;
      localStorage.setItem("gridData", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
  actions: {
    loadData({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get("/data/eventsData.json")
        .then((response) => {
          commit("setEventsData", response.data);
          commit("setLoading", false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, just a few things to note:

> I dispatch a "loadData" action in created() of App.js and then calling a local function 'prepareData'

No, you're not. The axios call is asynchronous and you do not wait for it to finish before calling your `prepareData()` method. If you need proof, clear your localStorage and slow down your network using your browser dev tools. You could fix it like so:

```js
loadData({ commit }) {
    return axios
        .get("/data/eventsData.json")
        .then((response) => {
            commit("setEventsData", response.data);
            commit("setLoading", false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

```js
this.$store.dispatch("loadData").then(() => {
    this.prepareData();
});
```

That being said, I don't thing you should do this in your Vue component. I would suggest moving this method to your store to call it in the `then` method of your `axios` call. It would make things way easier if you ever want to refresh your data from another component and it keeps your Vue file smaller.

Also, I would suggest not using the `delete` keyword as the would mutate the objects inside the `eventsData` array as well (same reference). Just re-create an object using [the ES6 spread operator syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

And finally, did you consider using a vuex `getter` instead of storing a modified version of the `eventsData` array?

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but I ended up using my setLoading state which also worked. i.e. `if (!this.loading) this.prepareData();`